# Bounded function and Derivatives

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential, differential-algebra

Does eventually all the successive derivatives of a bounded functions become bounded if one of them becomes bounded?(for entire number line case)

Comment: No, take for example $f(x) = \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is bounded, with unbounded derivative

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't. Consider
$$
\sin(x^2)
$$
which is clearly bounded, but whose derivatives all are very much unbounded.

However, if your function is defined on a closed and bounded interval, and all its derivatives exist everywhere (and are therefore all continuous), then they must be bounded.

Comment: @AnshulArgrawal None of the derivatives are bounded. So they aren't eventually bounded either. As opposed to a polynomial, whose derivatives are all eventually $0$ and therefore bounded.

Comment: The  second example need a correction.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It's usually better to point out exactly what the typo is, so I understand that that's what you mean. I first thought you meant the function itself needed a correction.

Comment: OK, sorry about that.

Comment: @Arthur thanks.Is it possible that a function's derivative oscillates between being bounded and unbounded?

Comment: @AnahulAgrawal I want to say "no". If a function is bounded but has unbounded derivative, then it must oscillate faster and faster. Thus the derivative oscillates with basically the same frequency, but it's unbounded, so _its_ derivative must be unbounded, and have even higher amplitude. And so on. However, without sitting down and typing out a proof (presumably using the mean value theorem frequently), I might be missing some subtlety.